# Getting a file from current package

Tags: java, file, path

This code runs well in my locally but gives file not found exception when we build using bamboo. Any idea/workaround?

```
final static String FILE_NAME ="/src/test/java/com/statement/SamplePDFStatementFile.txt";
file = new File(FILE_NAME);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
```

I basically want to test a class which reads a file.  Here is the Complete Code.

```
//Main Class
public class PdfRenderer {

    public void render(PdfFile pdfFile) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pdfFile.getFile());

        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", " attachment; filename=" + pdfFile.getAttachmentName());

        byte[] buff = new byte[2048];
        int bytesRead;
        while (-1 != (bytesRead = fis.read(buff, 0, buff.length))) {
            response.getOutputStream().write(buff, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        response.getOutputStream().flush();

    }
}

//Test

public class PdfRendererTest{

    PdfFile pdfFile;
    File file;

    @Test
    public void test_DetailStatementsByAccountNumber() throws Exception {
        new AbstractSeamTest.ComponentTest() {

            PdfRenderer actionBean = new PdfRenderer();

            URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/SamplePDFStatementFile.txt");
            final String FILE_NAME = url.getFile();

            protected void testComponents() throws Exception {

                file = new File(FILE_NAME);

                context.checking(new Expectations() {{
                    one(pdfFile).getFile();
                    will(returnValue(file));
                    one(pdfFile).getAttachmentName();
                    will(returnValue(file.getName()));
                }});

                actionBean.render(pdfFile);
            }

        }.run();
    }
}
```

I want to set an expectation that pdfFile.getFile() returns SamplePDFStatementFile.txt. If I use getResourceAsStream, am not sure how to convert it to a File Object.

OK.. so now I am using. Looks like thats the answer :)

```
public void inputStreamToFile() throws Exception{
                InputStream inputStream =  this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/SamplePDFStatementFile.txt");

                file = File.createTempFile("abc","def");
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

                int length = 0;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

                while ((length = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                       out.write(bytes, 0, length);
                }

                inputStream.close();
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            }
```

Comment: It gives the exception when you *build* it or when you *run* it?

Comment: See about using a `getResource` method from a classloader (context classloader, or the one that loaded your current class), using a path starting from the root package (`com`). You're using an absolute path, it would seem.

Comment: Also looks like the file is under the SRC folder, typically builds exclude the SRC folder, could you check that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no reliable ways to reference files relative to the project root folder.

You need to reference this file as a resource instead. As far as I see, you use Maven. If so, you need to put this file into `/src/test/resources` rather than `/src/test/java` (perhaps you can also configure Maven to get resources from `/src/test/java`, but it would be a violation of Maven directory layout convention).

After that you can load this file as

```
InputStream fis = getClass()
    .getResourceAsStream("/com/statement/SamplePDFStatementFile.txt");
```

Or, if the current class is in the `com.statement` package, as

```
InputStream fis = getClass().getResourceAsStream("SamplePDFStatementFile.txt");
```

Comment: As per your suggestion I have put the text file under `src/test/resources/SamplePDFStatementFile.txt`  and in my main class which is in `src/test/java/com/billmelater/csa/action/statement/PdfRendererTest.java` I do `InputStream fis = getClass().getResourceAsStream("SamplePDFStatementFile.txt");` but it returns null

Comment: @Himalay: Since your package of your class doesn't correspond to the folder of your resource, you need to use full path as follows: `getResourceAsStream("/SamplePDFStatementFile.txt")`.

Comment: Thanks axtavt.. you made my day..Just one last clarifaction is if the code below looks ok to you (execution wise). Don't want to break the build again.
  `URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/SamplePDFStatementFile.txt");`
  `final String FILE_NAME = url.getFile();`        
  `file = new File(FILE_NAME);`
  `FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pdfFile.getFile());`

Comment: @Himalay: This code looks strange and perhaps won't work if your application is packed into `jar` file. What's wrong with `getResourceAsStream()`?

Comment: Basically I am looking for a File object instance that refer to a physical file .  File file ---> SamplePDFStatementFile.txt

Comment: @Himalay: Your approach with `URL` is a hack, but if it works it should be fine for tests, since they are not packaged into `jar`s. As a right, but more complicated approach you can copy contents of your resource into temp file created with `File.createTempFile()`.

Comment: I used File.createTempFile(), please have a look at the last updated code in my Question. Hope its safe now. Thanks a bunch!